# n-zero-packed array is a The function returns true if its array argument is n-zero-packed

Tags: java, arrays

An array is defined to be n-zero-packed if it contains two or more non-zero elements and exactly n zeroes separate all non-zero elements that would be adjacent if the zeroes were removed. For example, the array {1, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, -8, 0, 0} is 2-zero-packed because there are two zeroes between the 1 and the 18 and two zeroes between the 18 and the -8 and this accounts for all the non-zero elements. The array {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4} is not 2-zero-packed because there are three zeroes between the 1 and the 6 and only one zero between the 6 and the 8
Write a function named isNZeroPacked with the following signature
boolean isNZeroPacked(int[] a, int n)
The function returns true if its array argument is n-zero-packed (note that n is passed as one of the arguments of the function

Examples

1. {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0}
   n= 1
   ans => True || 1;
   because exactly 1 zero separates all the non-zero elements of the array
2. {12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8}
   n=7
   ans= true || 1
   because exactly 7 zeroes separate all the non-zero elements of the array
3. {0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6}
   n=2
   ans = true || 1
   because exactly 2 zeroes separate all the non-zero elements of the array
4. {0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6}
   n=2
   ans = false || 0
   because there are three zeroes between the 4 and the 6.
5. {0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6}
   n=2
   ans= false || 0
   because there is only one zero between the 5 and the 4.
6. {0, 0, 0, 0}
   n=3
   ans= false 0
   because array must have at least two non-zero elements
7. {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
   n=2
   ans= false || 0
   because array must have at least two non-zero elements

Note: zeroes at the beginning and end of the array should be ignored. my solutions is down here, any shorter and a simpler code is appreciated

```
 private static boolean isNzeroPack(int[] arr, int n) {

        boolean firstIf = false;
        boolean secondIf = false;
        boolean satisfied=false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != 0) {
                for (int j = i, k = 1; j < arr.length; k++, j++) {
                    if (i - k >= 0 && !firstIf && arr[i - k] != 0) {
                        if (j - i != n) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            firstIf = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (((j + 1) < arr.length) && !secondIf && (arr[j + 1] != 0)) {
                        if (j - i != n) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            secondIf = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
                satisfied = true;
            }
            firstIf = false;
            secondIf = false;

        }
        return satisfied;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on some **possible** solution using regular expressions:

1. Get the String representation of the array:

   From:`{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 };`

   To: `0002020200`
2. Remove leading and trailing zeros from the string.

   so, what we have so far is: `20202`
3. Now you have to options:

   3.1. If resulting string length is < 2 `return false`. This fits the two non-zero elements requirement.

   3.2. If >= 2 return matching with regex `^(((-*)[1-9]+)([0]{" + n + "})+)+((-*)[1-9]+)$` (it could be true or false depending on the case).

> The regex matches any quantity of numbers (negative included)
>   separated by n zeros between them.

---

### Implementation:

This implementation takes the input from your question (you could test it further) and return true or false after previous pseudo-algorithm evaluation. I also print the current string (from step 2) with informational purposes.

#### MainProgram:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Nzero
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {

        int [ ] arr1 = { 0 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 };
        int [ ] arr2 = { 12 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , - 8 };
        int [ ] arr3 = { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 5 , 0 , 0 , 4 , 0 , 0 , 6 };
        int [ ] arr4 = { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 5 , 0 , 0 , 4 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 6 };
        int [ ] arr5 = { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 5 , 0 , 4 , 0 , 0 , 6 };
        int [ ] arr6 = { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 };
        int [ ] arr7 = { 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 };

        System.out.println ( isNzeroPack ( arr1 , 1 ) ); // true
        System.out.println ( isNzeroPack ( arr2 , 7 ) ); // true
        System.out.println ( isNzeroPack ( arr3 , 2 ) ); // true
        System.out.println ( isNzeroPack ( arr4 , 2 ) ); // false
        System.out.println ( isNzeroPack ( arr5 , 2 ) ); // false
        System.out.println ( isNzeroPack ( arr6 , 3 ) ); // false
        System.out.println ( isNzeroPack ( arr7 , 2 ) ); // false

    }

    private static boolean isNzeroPack ( int [ ] arr , int n )
    {

        String numbers = Arrays.toString ( arr ).replaceAll ( "\\[|\\]|,|\\s" , "" );
        numbers = numbers.replaceAll ( "[0]+$" , "" );
        numbers = numbers.replaceFirst ( "^0+(?!$)" , "" );
        //informational print
        System.out.println ( numbers );

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ( "^(((-*)[1-9]+)([0]{" + n + "})+)+((-*)[1-9]+)$" );
        return numbers.length ( ) < 2 ? false : pattern.matcher ( numbers ).find ( );

    }

}
```

### Output:

```
20202
true
120000000-8
true
5004006
true
50040006
false
504006
false

false
1
false
```

**Note:** there is an empty line on the output (it's expected).

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much, you make it very simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

static int isNZeroPacked(int[] a, int n) {

```
    int nonZeroCount = 0;
    int zeroCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        
        boolean nZero = false;
        if(a[i] == 0)
            continue;
        else if(a[i] != 0 && i == a.length-1) {
            nonZeroCount++;
            break;
        }
            
        else if(a[i] != 0 && i != a.length-1) {
            
            nonZeroCount++;
            
            for(int j = i + 1; j <a.length; ++j) {
                if(a[j] != 0)
                    break;
                zeroCount++;
                if(a[a.length-1] == 0 )
                    zeroCount = n;
                
                if(zeroCount == n)
                    nZero = true;
            }
            
        }
        
        if(!nZero)
            return 0;
    }
    if(nonZeroCount < 2)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).